# How to reassemble TCP packets in Python?

Tags: python, tcp, packet

How to reassemble TCP packets in Python? Is there any existing tools for this?

Thanks! :-)

Comment: reassemble from what data source?

Comment: more detail is needed for an accurate answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To do perform TCP reassembly you'll need to use something like pynids http://jon.oberheide.org/pynids/.

You can also build your own using pylibpcap, dpkt or scapy.

TCP reassembly is very tricky with a LOT of edge cases. I wouldn't recommend doing it yourself if you need a robust solution.

Answer (score 5):

Yes... the TCP protocol guarantees that the application layer will only see packets assembled and in order. Now if you are talking about building some low level interface parsing the IP packet itself, you can take a stab at it with [RAW sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_socket) which should give you access to IP header information. Here's an example:

```
import socket

# the public network interface
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

# create a raw socket and bind it to the public interface
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)
s.bind((HOST, 0))

# Include IP headers
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)

# receive all packages
s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)

# receive a package
print s.recvfrom(65565)

# disabled promiscuous mode
s.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_OFF)
```

lifted shamelessly from the python socket module documentation:
http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html